# How do I split content of a string array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a following string array:

```
string[] match = { "9582.jpg+0003_2.wav", "9500.jpg+0001_2.wav", "9400.jpg+0103_2.wav"};
```

Above string array is a unique combination of image file and sound file. I have used '+' to separate these two files (not compulsory).

I would like to separate the content of my array and assign it to two variables. For example:

```
image0 = "9582.jpg";
sound0 = "0003_2.wav";

image1 = "9500.jpg";
sound1 = "0001_2.wav";

image2 = "9400.jpg";
sound2 = "0103_2.wav";
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you googled how to split a string in C#? What did you find? Do you know how to loop over an IEnumerable?

Comment: You can use Linq, something like `match.Select(x => x.Split('+')`

Comment: Loop through the array. And do `file.Split('+')` on each

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows no minimal search on OP side

Comment: If you have separate file name to begin with, *don't* combine them like this. Use a tuple or record instead. Or a 2D array

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 2D array sounds good. I am looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you always will have strings in this format you can leverage LINQ's `SelectMany` with `Select` with indexer for splitted strings:

```
string[] match = { "9582.jpg+0003_2.wav", "9500.jpg+0001_2.wav", "9400.jpg+0103_2.wav"};
var files = match
    .SelectMany(s => s.Split("+").Select((s, i) => (i, s))) // split string and turn result in value tuple containing "file type" and file name
    .GroupBy(t => t.i) // group by "type"
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(t => t.s).ToArray());
var images = files[0];
var sounds = files[1];
```

Comment: Generally you should not answer a question that's just asking you to write the code for them. That promotes the view that Stack Overflow is a code writing service.

Comment: @Guru Stron, Thank for your code. Split command does the job in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it rather easily with a simple `.Select` using LINQ!

`var result = match.Select(item => item.Split('+')).ToArray();`

Comment: Not my downvote for such a little error, but I can see you have splitted using a string. That doesn't compile. (In NET Framework while it works in Core)

Comment: Generally you should not answer a question that's just asking you to write the code for them. That promotes the view that Stack Overflow is a code writing service.

Comment: @Steve Splitting using a string compiles just fine on my machine, I did check it since i hadn't done it in a long while.

Comment: Yes if you use Net.Core

Comment: @mason Does it say this anywhere in the SO house rules? The question is very trivial but we all had to start somewhere, I don't mind helping beginning programmers. I would normally refrain from answering a question that requires me to write an entire function but this is just the one line.

Comment: It doesn't have to say it in the rules. It's a convention and a general practice. Answering questions like this just promotes the wrong usage of Stack Overflow. Rather than just giving the code, it's better to teach them to research first and make an attempt at solving their problem. Then if they get stuck, they can create a [mcve] and we can answer that.

Comment: I agree with you if you'd say that this is the ideal situation. However I do believe OP has learned something by touching LINQ for the first time here. 
> It's a convention and a general practice, it is not my general practice or convention. If SO encourages me somewhere to behave as you've said then that'd be fine with me. E.g. their how to ask page encourages people to ask good questions. Does there exist anything like that on which questions to answer? If not then I guess you and I just disagree on that subject, which does not warrant a downvote in my book.